# Assigning Failed Unit Tests with more granularity?

Tags: sonarqube

I am searching a way to assign failed unit tests to resolvers. The way Sonar raises an issue at a class level whenever one or more unit tests fail does not fit my needs, I would like to assign a specific test to a specific developer.

Since Sonar can raise an issue for unit tests failures and is able to determine which particular test case failed I wonder if there is a way I could assign each failed test case to a different developer rather than the whole test class. And if it is possible, how can I do such a thing ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is not possible for the moment. You can indeed assign only the issue that tells how many errors (or failures) you have on a specific file. Most of the time, this will work out of the box as most teams try to avoid having people working on the same class at the same time. But it's true that this can happen.

Comment: I guess this applies to "age" of the test case failure as well.